# Install Windows Server 2008 Standard R2 on Poweredge 4600

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization

Is this possible if I install VmWare ESXi on the hardware?
I'd overcome Windows 2008 64bit limitations?
Or is it just too old and I should stick with 2003?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see here it is ESXi 4.1 U1 is not supported:

http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php?source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://www.vmware.com/go/hcl&rct=j&q=esxi%20hardware%20compatibility%20list&ei=I2FbTv37NseM4gTQqs2sBQ&usg=AFQjCNEXuH3H1BNILfm7AMoBNO0jQXhT-g

Comment: I am weeping silently.